# Code creates two MySQL rows instead of one

Tags: php, mysqli, joomla

I´m trying to create just one new row in a MySQL table

The problem is that I´m getting two new rows in my database.

I really can´t see why this is happening. The **debug_to_console( "makepass" );** - *my debug function* - only gets executed once? AND the two rows it creates is not identical/copies

```
debug_to_console( "makepass" );

$salt = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
$len = strlen($salt);
$makepassJBH = '';
for ($i = 57; $i < $len; $i ++) {
        $makepassJBH .= $salt[mt_rand(0, $len -1)];
}
$newpassJBH = password_hash($makepassJBH, PASSWORD_BCRYPT );            

$licensidentifierJBH = '';
for ($i = 57; $i < $len; $i ++) {
        $licensidentifierJBH .= $salt[mt_rand(0, $len -1)];
}
$fullkey = $makepassJBH . $licensidentifierJBH;


try {           
    // Get a db connection.
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();

    // Create a new query object.
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    // Insert columns.
    $columns = array('licenskey','licenskey_Identifier','dateCreated', 'printed');

    // Insert values.
    $values = array($db->quote($newpassJBH), $db->quote($licensidentifierJBH), $db->quote(date("Y-m-d")), $db->quote(0));

    // Prepare the insert query.
    $query
        ->insert($db->quoteName('#__licenskey'))
        ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
        ->values(implode(',', $values));

    $query .= ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ' . $db->quoteName('licenskey_Identifier') . ' = VALUES(' . $db->quoteName('licenskey_Identifier') . ')';
    // Set the query using our newly populated query object and execute it.
    $db->setQuery($query);
    echo $db->replacePrefix((string) $query);
    $db->execute();
}
```

The SQL dump:

```
INSERT INTO `mdh_licenskey` (`licenskey`,`licenskey_Identifier`,`dateCreated`,`printed`) VALUES ('$2y$10$jXkjJX1OZ7Vu0okV/QlxcehF5T2SSPZFhVHIx.E64HhidgYY.3URS','juLEo','2018-07-23','0') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `licenskey_Identifier` = VALUES(`licenskey_Identifier`)
```

Comment: After `$db->setQuery($query);`, could you try dumping the actual SQL query? `debug_to_console($db->replacePrefix((string) $query));` - As a side note, you should change `$db->query()` to `$db->execute()` since query is [deprecated](https://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase).

Comment: @AndersCarstensen this is the output: INSERT INTO `mdh_licenskey` (`licenskey`,`licenskey_Identifier`,`dateCreated`,`printed`) VALUES ('$2y$10$jXkjJX1OZ7Vu0okV/QlxcehF5T2SSPZFhVHIx.E64HhidgYY.3URS','juLEo','2018-07-23','0') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `licenskey_Identifier` = VALUES(`licenskey_Identifier`)

Comment: Okay. My best guess that the whole code is being run twice, including the `debug_to_console( "makepass" );` (perhaps the console is being cleared between runs?). So the error is probably not in the code, but _how you run it_. If you want help with debugging it, perhaps you could explain how you run it.

Comment: @AndersCarstensen I´m testing it through Chrome with the "Preserve log" enabled. The `makepass` is only printed once in the log - so I can´t see why it this is happening :-( ..... The code is inside a plugin for Joomla j2Store - so could be run twice, but then I don´t understand why ´makepass´ only gets printed once

Comment: Could you try placing an `exit;` before `$db->execute();` and verify that nothing is written to the database? Then move the `exit;` until _after_ `$db->execute();` and verify that it now writes **two entries**. This way we are sure it is this specific line that is failing.

Comment: @AndersCarstensen I tried it and can verify that nothing gets written with `exit;` before `execute` and `exit;` after writes two entries

Comment: You are saying the values are different. I assume that includes license key. Since the license key is generated by the PHP code above, that code must be executed twice. Is the browser somehow making two calls to your php file?

Comment: @AndersCarstensen Hmm... good point! But It is the same in Explorer and Firefox... and the Chrome log just says it navigated to the page once

Comment: @AndersCarstensen you where right! The code got excuted twice. I moved the code to another part of the class it where in and now it works.. can you post is as an answer so I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the license key is generated by the PHP code above, that code must be executed twice. This can happen for multiple reasons but it can be difficult for us to guess exactly why. Either check if your browser is calling it twice, or if it is called twice from within the PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your script isn't executed twice. I had this issue when using firebug for example. This plugin made my page execute twice but not outputting to the console.
Sort of like a "prefetch" of the page before showing, don't know for sure.

Maybe add a 'debug to console' point on every line, like 'here 1, here 2'..

Comment: That would really make sense... but unfortunately its´s the same in every browser. And trying with the debug console for every step, the coments only gets written once

Comment: I wouldn't rely to much on the console part. Maybe add a 'file_put_contents' part that appends timestamps (with a reference) at each line and then open the outputted file yourself to actually determine if it was executed twice.